# Listing main OpenStreetMap-based sites

Tags: openstreetmap

I don't like the way the standard [OSM maps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) look (too much details), and would like to check if some OSM-based services are better than Google Maps.

"[List of OSM based Services](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/List_of_OSM_based_Services)" doesn't list them by popularity.

What are the main sites that use OSM maps for general purposes (ie. alternative to GoogleMaps)?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the services by MapBox (particularly 'streets') CloudMade, MapQuest Open and Stamen. These map services all use OSM and have applied their own style or allow you to style them yourself.